# importing an aspx page into silverlight in expression blend

Tags: silverlight-4.0, asp.net, sketchflow

I have an aspx masterpage that I would like to use in Sketchflow in ExpressionBlend as a Silverlight project. I am totally out of my comfort zone here and am not even sure how to ask this question. This masterpage has a Header and a Footer and the middle section will contain the Content - which will actually be Silverlight. Is there some easy method to bring the design (aspx) into Sketchflow to use? Again, so sorry for my lack of knowledge in this area to be able to ask a more informed question. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blend edits only Silverlight or WPF content and won't be able to edit your aspx page. What you can do is develop the silverlight content in Blend, then take the built .xap file for inclusion into your aspx page.

By default Blend will create an html file that does nothing but include your silverlight app fullscreen.

Comment: Hi Chuck,
Thanks for the quick reply! And the answer is what I figured, I just didn't know if there was some way to show the header and footer in the Sketchflow so when we give it to users they could see that as well.
thanks!
Bill